# Need Resources on XAPO Effects for XAudio2

Tags: c++, windows, audio, xaudio2

I've been working with XAudio2 lately.  After going over the samples, example code, and more-sparse-than-I'd-like documentation available from Microsoft and the MSDN, I've found that there aren't any easy-to-Google resources on creating and using XAPO effects, nor any XAPO effects produced by third parties that I can download and/or buy.

So, what it looks like is that if I create an app that uses XAPO effects, I'll have to create them all myself because there's no robust community of existing applications like there is with technologies like Apple's AU or Steinberg's VST.  Is this true, or are there others using XAudio2 and XAPO and I just haven't found them?

Is there a place to ask programmer-support-related questions about XAudio2 and related technologies (or is StackOverflow the best destination)?  The best I've found so far are the XNA forums, which are game-specific and sparsely trafficked in the audio area, so not all that useful.

Answer (score 1):

There does indeed to be very little out there so it seems like MSDN is likely the best bet for now.

Here are a few articles\threads that came up :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/8716.aspx